# Bot Framework Webchat links onclick in React

Tags: reactjs, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

Because of other services that are integrated to the bot, we have to use HTML anchors instead of the markdown.

When there is a link, we dynamically switch it to the following code:

`var newStr = sub.replace('*|', '<a class="chatbot-link" title="help" href="#" onClick={this.click}>').replace('*', '</a>');`

The goal is when the link is clicked, I sends the text content back to the bot as a response. The issue is that I cannot figure out how to catch the onclick event. Only thing it does when click is that it generates a seperate index.js in the page sources.

The base of the code I am using is a github webchat sample: [Link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.recomposing-ui)

The code added that is important for the example (in MinimizableWebChat.js):

```
const MinimizableWebChat = (activityID, children) => {
  const store = useMemo(
    () =>
      createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {

        console.log(action.type);

        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
          dispatch({
            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
            payload: {
              name: 'initConversation',
              value: {
                language: window.navigator.language
              }
            }
          });
        } else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
          if (action.payload.activity.from.role === 'bot') {
            setNewMessage(true);
            // action.payload.activity.text = action.payload.activity.text;        
            // action.payload.activity.text = ();

             action.payload.activity.text = ParseLinks(action.payload.activity.text);

            var atts = action.payload.activity.attachments;
            if (atts){
              atts.forEach(att => {
                att.content.body.forEach(obj => {
                  obj.text = EmphasizeContent(obj.text);
                })
              });
            }
          }        
       }

        return next(action);
      }),
    []
  );

  const items = ["Hello World!", "My name is TJ.", "I am from Denver."];

      var text = "asd";

  // const click = () => {
  //   store.dispatch({
  //     type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX',
  //     payload: {
  //       text
  //     }
  //   });
  // }

  const ParseLinks = (text) => {
    if(!text) return text;

    text = String(text);
    var a=[], i=-1;

    // Search for *|, if found, find next * and substirng. Add html to each substring    
    while((i=text.indexOf("*|",i+1)) >= 0) {
      var iA = text.indexOf("*", i+2);
      var sub = text.substring(i,iA+1);
      // var newStr = sub.replace('*|', '<a class="chatbot-link" title="help" href="#" onClick={this.click}>').replace('*', '</a>');
      var newStr = sub.replace('*|', '<a class="chatbot-link" title="help" href="#" onClick={this.click}>').replace('*', '</a>');

      text = text.replace(sub, newStr);
    } 
    return text;
  }
```

I tried catching it in the middleware store and directly in bot MinimizableWebChat.js and WebChat.js. I need somekind of hook to get the event from ReactWebChat in some way to interact with it in the middleware.

Fyi, pretty new to React, thanks for the help.

Comment: In simple terms, what text is it that you are trying to send back to the bot? I'm assuming this is coming from some button click. Is this button on the page or part of some activity coming from the bot (i.e. a card of some type)? Lastly, are you wanting the minimizable functionality or did you select the sample because it has code you are trying to utilize?

Comment: Hi Steven. I am trying to add an event listener to a <a href>. Right now, I replace the text with the html, and it shows the link properly, but the onClick in the HTML doesn't reach the functions created in either component for some reason. Right now I am trying to inject a React component instead to see if that will work.

Comment: What kind of activity is it that contains the "<a href>" link? Is it a card (what kind) or something else that is coming from the bot?

Comment: On a side note, I have noticed that adding a setTimeout of 300 ms to changes/calls in the 'store' is beneficial. Without it, the action you are taking occurs before the store can finish processing the activity and displaying it. 300 ms seems optimal - any shorter and and they miss each other, any longer and it becomes noticeable to the user. It might be a red herring in your case, but worth trying. Try wrapping the setTimeout around the code contained in the `if (action.payload.activity.from.role === 'bot') { ... }` to start.